# При повторном заходе на страницу остается старый контент

Tags: javascript, jquery

Попробую описать словами проблему...
Есть приложение, которое формирует страницу динамически, заполняя ее данными с сервера. В результате получается список в виде названий имущества. Если кликнуть по названию открывается всплывающее модальное окно, которое содержит подробные свойства этого имущества (также динамически подгружаемые с сервера и заполняющие модальную страницу). Модальное окно содержит кнопку, по клику на которую срабатывает функция, которая закрывает это окно и мы, соответственно, опять видим, ранее сформированную, страницу со списком названий имущества. Если повторно кликнуть уже на другое имущество в списке, то, в появившемся новом модальном окне остаются старые свойства предыдущего имущества и добавляются новые, что является ошибкой.
Никак не могу понять - как сделать так, чтобы старые свойства затирались при повторном клике на другое название имущества из списка и отображались только новые? Надо добавить какое-то условие перед динамическим созданием модального окна? Или "занулять" все поля, которые создаются в модальном окне?
Вот кусок кода, который выбирает из списка то, на что кликнули и вызывает далее функции, которые заполняют модальное окно:

```
// Choice index of property in array of ID within local storage by click 
$("#ownProperty").click(function(e) { 
    var elem = e.target || event.srcElement;
    var elemA =  $(elem).closest("a"); // look for nearest element with tag "a"
    var currentId = +$(elemA).attr("id"); // get value "id"

    var userId = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("id") );
    var index = userId.indexOf(currentId); // return index of element

    createRental(index, currentId);
    createInspection(index, currentId);
});
```

ДОБАВИЛ:

Вот кусок одной из функций заполнения:

```
function createRental(index, currentId) {
    var propertyName = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("propertyName") );
    var singlePropertyName = propertyName[index];
    var $userProperty = $("<p/>", {
        id: "propertyNAME",
        text: singlePropertyName
    });
    var elem2 = document.getElementById('propertyNAME');

    if (!elem2) {
        // Create single property in the top navbar
        $(".userProperty").append($userProperty);
    };

    var userMeta = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("meta") );
    var singleMeta = userMeta[index];
    var userPrices = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("prices") );
    var singlePrices = userPrices[index];

    // Review field "is_sale". If true - 1 field, else - 2
    if (singleMeta.is_sale == true) {
        // Dynamically create the variables for Sale Price RENTAL AMOUNT form
        var $liRental1 = $("<li/>", {
            id: currentId + "sale"
        });
        var $divRental11 = $("<div/>", {
            class: "item-content"
        });
        var $divRental12 = $("<div/>", {
            class: "item-inner"
        });
        var $divRental13 = $("<div/>", {
            class: "item-title label",
            text: "Sale Price"
        });
        var $divRental14 = $("<div/>", {
            class: "item-input"
        });
        var $inputRental1 = $("<input>", {
            autocomplete: "off",
            type: "text",
            name: "priceAdvertiseAs",
            value: singlePrices.price_advertise_as
        });
        var elem3 = document.getElementById(currentId + "sale");

        if (!elem3) {
            // Dynamically create the Sale Price RENTAL AMOUNT form 
            $("#rental").append($liRental1);
            $liRental1.append($divRental11);
            $divRental11.append($divRental12);
            $divRental12.append($divRental13);
            $divRental12.append($divRental14);
            $divRental14.append($inputRental1);
        };  };
```

Она работает не корректно.Т.е. поле `singlePropertyName` остается тем же, при клике на другое название из списка, и старое поле `singlePrices.price_advertise_as` также не затирается - к нему добавляется  новое...

Comment: Приведённый код не даёт практически никакой информации для ответа (ни как добавляются данные в окна, ни как окна создаются, ни как закрываются).  Единственное что могу посоветовать это удалть то что есть в окнах перед тем как добавлять в них новый контент.

Comment: "функции, которые заполняют модальное окно" - понятно же, что эти функции не очищают старое содержимое.`$("#ownProperty")` - вызывает подозрение в повторяющихся атрибутах `id`.

Comment: @Arnial, там окло 400 строк кода, я не выкладывал... Как проще всего занулить данные перед тем как добавляем контент?

Comment: @Igor, с атрибутами все нормально, если вы имеете в виду функции в конце кода. Они заполняют разные формы, но из одного и того же объекта...

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать пример на jsfiddle.net но с большим куском когда мало кто захочет разбираться. Добавьте, хотябы,  код одной из функций занимаетщихся заполнением.

Comment: @Arnial, добавил код одной из функций...

Comment: Вот у вас после `if (!elem3) ` стоит Append, выходит информация добавится, а чистить  #rental  надо? Вот может и выходит что в #rental добавляются новые данные а старые остаются?

Comment: @nick_n_a, да, у меня как раз, похоже с этим затык и есть. Как лучше очистить?

Comment: Я бы сделал так  `$("#rental").innerHTML = '';` может правельнее как-то по другому. Может быть  $("#rental").html("")

Comment: Вот, на jquery так очистка: `$("#rental").empty();`

Comment: @nick_n_a, да я уже пробовал очистку на jquery - не корректно работает, затирает необходимые поля. Спасибо, буду думать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, решил этот вопрос добавив функцию, которая подвешена на закрытие модального окна. Функция стирает все элементы методом ".remove()". Соответственно при новом вызове модального окна оно девственно чисто)

Answer (score 0):

это проблема сервера, а не клиента. Вам на сервере надо ограничить время жизни запрашиваемой страницы, я с этим сталкивался.

Если сервер IIS на c# надо добавить в ответе сервера (в OnLoad или перед Response.End) `Response.Cashe.SetExpires(DateTime.MinValue)` если нет, почитайте аналог SetExpires или ExpiresDate для вашего сервера. Иначе кеш сервера отдаёт устаревшую инфу.

На php это делается так: `header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 0 ));`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036941/setup-http-expires-headers-using-php-and-apache

Можно так же почитать спецификацию протокола http, тут есть https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать об этом, но, вероятно, в моем случае дело в другом. Я все данные предворительно загрузил в local storage и уже оттуда заполняю необходимые поля в модальном окне, запрос на сервер не посылаю.

Comment: Согласен, я не вчитался в вопрос, увидев JSON я подумал что вы динамически подгружаете данные (ф-цию загрузки, её не было). А у вас проблема с выводом. Тогда я удаляю ответ?